# Jsoup как добавить текст к элем

Tags: java, html, jsoup

Вывожу из  jsoup html страницу,  хочу чтобы ссылки работали 
Пример

```
 <p class="p"><a href="/doc/word.doc" target="_blank">Текст</a></p>
```

Нужно к `a href="/doc/word.doc"` добавить `a href="сайт.рф/doc/word.doc"` ,можно другими способами вроде к примеру `js target="_blank"` .
`loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", text, "text/html", "utf-8", null);` - уже используется

Нашел способ

```
elWeb = elements.html();
 elWeb = elWeb.replace("href=\"", "href=\"http://сайт.рф/");
```

Но теперь заметно долго открывается, есть другие варианты?

Comment: попробуйте `loadDataWithBaseURL("http://сайт.рф/", text, "text/html", "utf-8", null);`

Comment: Можете ещё попробовать получить с помощью Jsoup все ссылки на странице, пройтись по ним в цикле и исправить атрибут href. На оф. сайте пример есть. Возможно, будет быстрее.